# Get value from MS Access file

Tags: java, ms-access

I want user to give me an input. The input will be my primary key in ms access file (an integer, like 00 or 567) and then I want my method to look for it in my database and print out the record from ms access.

I've got connection and everything set-up already, I know how to print all of them.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: So you *know* how to execute a query against the MS Access DB but don't know how to provide a parameter to that Query? Then look at [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

Answer (score 1):

I realize this was asked a while ago - but it seems to me your looking for code similar to that i have entered below. If you replace the 'Reportname' with the actual name of the report your looking for, and the 'IDFromUser' obtains the value of the primary key, and 'RecordID' gets replaced by your primary key name, this function will open a report to a print preview of the specific record.

```
DoCmd.OpenReport Reportname, acViewPreview, , "RecordID=" & IDFromUser
```

And, if you want to make it really automatic, you can have the report go straight to PDF with the below script added on too.

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, strReportObject, acFormatPDF, strFileName, True, , , acExportQualityPrint
DoCmd.Close acReport, strReportObject, acSaveYes
```

Let me know if that helps - and if the one that asked is no longer watching, hopefully this helps someone else.